# PetaPoco, Passing a list to a stored procedure

Tags: c#, azure, stored-procedures, petapoco

I am trying to pass a list of objects to a stored procedure using petapoco which returns a message saying there is no managed native type to map my object type to and I do not fully understand why and how to correct it.

I am using Azure for my database where have created a Tabled-value parameter

```
 CREATE TYPE TransactionModel AS TABLE (
Id int,
UserName nvarchar(128),
RecordId int,
OrderId int,
Usd decimal(18,2),
Btc decimal(18,8),
BtcUsd decimal(18,2),
Fee decimal(18,2),
Type int,
DateTime datetime,
Updated datetime
)
```

I have a table that matches that called "Transactions"

My Sproc

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_SaveTransactions
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Transactions TransactionModel READONLY,
    @UserName nvarchar(128)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Transactions(UserName, RecordId, OrderId, Usd, Btc, BtcUsd, Fee, Type, DateTime, Updated)

    SELECT  UserName, RecordId, OrderId, Usd, Btc, BtcUsd, Fee, Type, DateTime, Updated
    FROM @Transactions
    END
END
GO
```

And finally my C# method

```
public static void SpSave<T>(T obj, string userName)
        {
            try
            {
                var ctx = new PetaPoco.Database("MyDatabase");

                if (obj.GetType().IsGenericType && obj is IEnumerable)
                {
                    var list = (IList)obj;
                    var l = ctx.Query<List<TransactionModel>>(";EXEC sp_SaveTransactions @0", list, userName);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The supported types for a table variable for SQL server from MSDN are a datatable, DbDataReader or SqlDataRecord. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You should be able to simply pass a SqlParameter in using PetaPoco with one of these data types.

```
var param = new SqlParameter();
param.DbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
param.ParameterName = "@Transaction";
param.SqlValue = table; // Datatable or one of the acceptable SqlClient types above

ctx.Query<List<TransactionModel>>(";exec sp_SaveTransactions  @0", param);
```